# Cocos2d returning to a scene

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

So basically I have a "whiteboard" scene that allows people to draw something on, and then you can go back to the original scene.

Which everything works fine, but lets say I draw a line, and go back to the original scene. I click on the whiteboard button, and the line which was originally there, is gone. I want the line to stay.

I've tried saving an instance of the CCScene like this,

```
-(CCScene*)getWhiteboardScene {
    if(whiteboardScene == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Set whiteboardscene.");
        whiteboardScene = [NewWhiteBoardTest node];
    }
    return whiteboardScene;
}
```

But after the first time I use the whiteboard, (when it sets it), it crashes the app with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Edit: Im starting the scene like this,

```
CCScene* scene = [self getWhiteboardScene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:scene];
```

So how should I be doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way - create singletone scene instance. Make your `whiteboardScene` static.

The second way is to create some scene controller and let it own(store and retain) all scene instances to be sure that them are not destroyed after being replaced.